# In R, what is a good way to aggregate String data

Tags: r, statistics, s-plus

In R (or S-PLUS), what is a good way to aggregate String data in a data frame?

Consider the following:

```
myList <- as.data.frame(c("Bob", "Mary", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"))
```

I would like the output to be:

```
 [Bob,  3
  Mary, 1
  Joe,  1]
```

Currently, the only way I know how to do this is with the summary function.

```
> summary(as.data.frame(myList))

 Bob :3                                
 Joe :1                                
 Mary:1
```

This feels like a hack. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `table`, no need to sort:

```
ctable <- table(myList);
counts <- data.frame(Name = names(ctable),Count = as.vector(ctable));
```

Comment: you can simplify the last line to as.data.frame(ctable)

Note that the semicolons are only needed if you put more than one command on a line.

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of the above answers (as suggested by Thierry)

```
data.frame(table(myList[,1]))
```

which gives you

```
  Var1 Freq
1  Bob    3
2  Joe    1
3 Mary    1
```

Comment: It gives an error for me - a one liner based on Thierry's suggestion would be:  as.data.frame(table(myList))

Comment: That's interesting.  What kind of error message did you get?  I just tried it without getting an error message.

Comment: Scratch that - I tried it after defining myList as a list, not a data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
myList <- c("Bob", "Mary", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe")
r <- rle(sort(myList))
result <- as.data.frame(cbind(r$values, r$lengths))
names(result) <- c("Name", "Occurrences")
result
  Name Occurrences
1  Bob           3
2  Joe           1
3 Mary           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
myList <- data.frame(v1=c("Bob", "Mary", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"))
library(data.table)
     v1 N
1:  Bob 3
2: Mary 1
3:  Joe 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf` library:

```
require(sqldf)

myList<- data.frame(v=c("Bob", "Mary", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"))
sqldf("SELECT v,count(1) FROM myList GROUP BY v")
```